# How to manage a list of the different dimensions data frame (keep \Drop columns)?

Tags: r

I have a large list of data frames with different dimensions. The dimensions of my real data are too big, so I create a new list (myList) for an instant as follow:

```
myList <- list( data.frame(ID = c("T-02", "T-04","T-06"), 
                              Test = rnorm(3, mean=50, sd=10),Shape=c("C","S","r"), 
                              Time=rnorm(3, mean=90, sd=10),Event=c(1,0,1),
                              KPS=c(90,100,70),Sex=c("F","M","F"),Race=c("W","B","W")),
              
                data.frame(ID = c("T-02", "T-04","T-06"), Shape=c("C","S","r"),
                              Value = 1:3,Time=rnorm(3, mean=90, sd=10),
                              Event=c(1,0,1),
                              KPS=c(90,100,70),Sex=c("F","M","F"),Race=c("W","B","W")),
               data.frame(ID = c("T-02", "T-04","T-06"), 
                              Test = rnorm(3, mean=50, sd=10), 
                              Value = 1:3, Time=rnorm(3, mean=90, sd=10),Event=c(1,0,1),
                             KPS=c(90,100,70),Sex=c("F","M","F"),Race=c("W","B","W")),

                data.frame(ID = c("T-02", "T-04","T-06"), 
               Test = rnorm(3, mean=50, sd=10), 
               Value = 1:3,Time=rnorm(3, mean=90, sd=10),Event=c(1,0,1),
               KPS=c(90,100,70),Sex=c("F","M","F"),Race=c("W","B","W")))
```

I looking for a function in which I can drop all columns after the "Event" column or select columns from the first to the "Event" column.
I can do it easily for such short data by the bellow code:

```
new_drop<-lapply(myList, function(x){x[,!names(x)%in%c("KPS","Sex","Race")]})
```

But I want to remove more than 20 columns like this in my data. I wonder if there is a simpler way.
I also tried this code but it did not work properly!

```
new_drop1<-lapply(myList, function(x){x[,endsWith(colnames(x),"Event")]})
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `grep`:

```
lapply(myList, function(x) x[seq(grep("Event", names(x)))])


[[1]]
    ID     Test Shape     Time Event
1 T-02 65.11001     C 94.53361     1
2 T-04 70.25636     S 84.86061     0
3 T-06 44.56480     r 85.30492     1

[[2]]
    ID Shape Value     Time Event
1 T-02     C     1 93.40279     1
2 T-04     S     2 85.78726     0
3 T-06     r     3 97.02140     1

[[3]]
    ID     Test Value     Time Event
1 T-02 39.89387     1 94.80438     1
2 T-04 48.28122     2 85.62445     0
3 T-06 49.47685     3 90.10609     1

[[4]]
    ID     Test Value     Time Event
1 T-02 38.55385     1 78.33900     1
2 T-04 47.60908     2 77.63453     0
3 T-06 43.59754     3 92.25645     1
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code allows you to keep only the previous columns to "Event", using `which`. `which` is a `base function` which returns the indexes that satisfy a set of conditions. Here the only condition is `colnames(x)=="Event"`.

```
new_drop<-lapply(myList, function(x){
  res <- NULL
  if(is.data.frame(x)) {
    eventcol <- which(colnames(x)=="Event")
    res <- x[,1:eventcol]
  } else {
    res <- x
  }
  return(res)
         })
```

This would work even if not all your `list` elements are of `class` `data.frame`

```
> lapply(new_drop, head)
[[1]]
    ID     Test Shape     Time Event
1 T-02 57.38475     C 76.05545     1
2 T-04 40.84934     S 85.98049     0
3 T-06 45.44281     r 85.18336     1

[[2]]
    ID Shape Value      Time Event
1 T-02     C     1 101.68492     1
2 T-04     S     2 100.13524     0
3 T-06     r     3  89.14877     1

[[3]]
    ID     Test Value     Time Event
1 T-02 42.92581     1 82.37073     1
2 T-04 42.10800     2 90.51706     0
3 T-06 50.51329     3 96.52649     1

[[4]]
    ID     Test Value     Time Event
1 T-02 49.13385     1 85.91036     1
2 T-04 52.72536     2 98.83747     0
3 T-06 68.96858     3 96.51575     1
```

Answer (score 0):

For each data frame you can find the number of columns with `ncol` and then the position of the Event column with the `which` function.  For example with mtcars assume the wt column is the "Event" column.

```
cars <- mtcars
ncols <- ncol(cars)
11
wt <- which(colnames(cars) == "wt")
6

# To remove columns 1 to to wt-1 and wt+1 to end

before <- wt - 1
cars1 <- cars[ , -(1:before)]
after <- wt + 1
cars2 <- cars[ , -(after:ncols)]
```

You can use the `sapply` function to find the dimensions of all your data frames and the positions of the Event column followed by an `lapply` to process the column deletions.